# Error "_colors.less" during static-content:deploy

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using **magento 2.1.4**

The command **$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** has always worked fine for me without any error.

Recently, in attempt to install new plugins, running the same command will crash the site and produce similar errors for all themes.

It seems to indicate that the compiler is looking for this **"_colors.less"** file which doesn't exist.

```
Compilation from source: 
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less'
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. There were files missing in the `lib` folder. To solve this, download a fresh copy of magento corresponding to your version. Then replace your present installation `lib` folder with the fresh installation.